# Google Maps geocode inside a listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I don't know why the r1 variable is undefined.
The **'latLng': mEvent.latLng** thing is working OK on other functions...

```
<!-- API V3 --> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

....

.....

....

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(mEvent) {

            var geo1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geo1.geocode( { 'latLng': mEvent.latLng }, function(results, status) {
                if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK )
                {
                    var r1 = results[0].formatted_address;
                }
                else
                {
                    var r1 = '?';
                }
            });

            //do things with mEvent.latLng and r1...
```

Comment: What's the value of `results` right before it is assigned to `r1`? Can you console.log?

Answer (score 1):

Variable r1 is most probably undefined because it's out of scope. You need to move it's declaration up a bit. E.g.:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(mEvent) {

        var geo1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var r1;
        geo1.geocode( { 'latLng': mEvent.latLng }, function(results, status) {
            if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK )
            {
                r1 = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
            else
            {
                r1 = '?';
            }
        });

        //do things with mEvent.latLng and r1...
```

If you still find some problem use Firebug (in Firefox) or built in debuggers in other browsers. You can insert "debugger;" keyword to stop at some line when a debugger is active. You will then be able to check what variables are available.